# Command keeps exiting, despite use of `nohup`

Tags: debian, nohup

What am I doing wrong here?

I Log into the first server (using putty) and run the following query:

```
sh -c 'nohup mysqldump -hxxx -Pxxx -uxxx -pxxx --dump-slave --include-master-host-port --apply-slave-statements -f -q -A -E -R | mysql -hxxxx -Pxxxx -uxxxx -pxxxx' &
```

If I look on the two databases I can see the MySQLDump is running on the first, and being imported on the second.

But the instance I close my Putty session, (or it times out) the mysqldump stops running. I thought that using `nohup` was supposed to keep it running??

As it's going to take apx 8 hours to run, I can't be sitting there looking at Putty for 8 hrs to stop it timing out.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro there is a pipeline in that command, so you do need to wrap it in `sh -c''` to keep the pipeline running. And you can't run `nohup mysqldump | nohup mysql` since `nohup` replaces STDIN and STDOUT for commands it runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you run the shell without `nohup`, it receives the `SIGHUP` signal when you close the session, and sends it to all processes in the pipeline. Since the second `mysql` command is, again, run without `nohup`, it termitates and sends `SIGPIPE` to `nohup mysqldump`, which in turn terminates.

Try

```
nohup sh -c 'mysqldump -hxxx -Pxxx -uxxx -pxxx --dump-slave --include-master-host-port --apply-slave-statements -f -q -A -E -R | mysql -hxxxx -Pxxxx -uxxxx -pxxxx' &
```

Comment: cheers, it seems I beat you to it by several months, but then forgot. I like the explanation though, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, and I'll admit I'm not entirely sure how myself, the `nohup` isn't protecting the correct bits. Fortunately, there is a solution - start this process inside a `screen` or `tmux` session on the first server. then you can disconnect the `screen` / `tmux` session and close your PuTTY window, and the MySQL dump / import will still be running.

Comment: cheers, that sounds like a good solution. (It turns out I actually asked (and answered) the same question back in March - simply put the `nohup` at the start of the string to protect the whole thing - I feel like such a dunce!!)